# Get soldats that were send out last week

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I want to know how many soldats were send out during the last week.

I wrote a query that returns me how many soldats were send out `today` as well as this `week`, but im wondering how to get the soldats that were send out `last week`.

My Query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id),
  SUM(CASE WHEN date(send_out) = current_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as today,
  SUM(CASE WHEN send_out >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '6d' 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as this_week
FROM soldats
```

I tried to add:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN 
         send_out >= date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '12d' 
         AND send_out < date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '6d' 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as last_week
```

But I am not sure if this is correct!

**How would you write this query?**

Comment: Other than the fact that a week generally has more than 6 days, this looks fine.  Have you tried it and checked the results?

Comment: Once again, your version of Postgres is a minimum requirement. Table definition should be there, too.